# Linking a section in another page nextjs

Tags: next.js

Is it possible to link to a section on another page in nextjs? So when i click on the link i get to a specific section on that page. I know it can be done is plain html but can it be done in nextjs? Something like this

```
<Link href='/#home-section'/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the next/link component to achieve this.

Don't forget to import it.

```js
import Link from 'next/link'
```

```js
<Link href="/about/#about" scroll={true}>
  <a>My about text</a>
</Link>
```

Here is the working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-cvjb2y?file=pages/about.js

If you wanna read more about the next/link here is the documentation.

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

Comment: i want to link to a section on another page not the same page

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Updated the code snippet for that.